# Customize jQuery pagination

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

I am using jQuery pagination plugin in my website.I use the below code.

```
<div id="ids"></div>

$(function () {
    $("#ids").paginate({
        count: 10,
        start: 1,
        display: 5,
        border: true,
        border_color: "#009933",
        text_color: "#000",
        background_color: "#95C25B",
        border_hover_color: "#ccc",
        text_hover_color: "#95C25B",
        background_hover_color: "#000",
        images: false,
        mouse: "press",
        onChange: function (e) {
          //some functions on selecting page number
        }
    });
});
```

I want to call some other function on clicking 'last' ( ie first and last li's) of page number.How can i give a specific function for 'last' of pagination number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the plugin works, but you're saying "last" and "first" li element, so maybe this will work?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('ul li').first().bind("click", function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
  });
  $('ul li').last().bind("click", function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
  });
});
```

I've created a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aDk6m/

Comment: No.When i used in that jquery pagination plugin it didnt work.Then I found some other solution.jQuery pagination plugin.